# C#/.NET API: [HttpPost] method returning 400 error in Postman, but [HttpGet] works fine - What am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, postman, http-post

C#/.NET endpoint works with [HttpGet] attribute, but not [HttpPost].

I am trying to send a Post request to an endpoint in an API. When I send the request using Postman I get a 400 error without it even hitting the endpoint method or breakpoint that I set. However if I use the [HttpGet] attribute on the method instead of [HttpPost] leaving everything else the same, then I get the response I expect. Because of this I assume there aren't any issues with the request itself and there must be something else going on. I expect it to return a 200 response.

In another controller class with the same format for a Post endpoint that also works as expected. It's only in this specific controller that it doesn't work.

Edited to include example method. If I change the [HttpPost] attribute to [HttpGet] then I get a 200 response, but with [HttpPost] I get a 400 before the endpoint is even hit.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/{orgId:guid}/[controller]")]
public class TestController: TestControllerBase
{        

        public TestController(
            IStatelessClientFactory<IIncrementalProcessorServiceClient> incrementalProcessorClientFactory,
            ILog log,
            IConfigurationRepository repository)
            : base(incrementalProcessorClientFactory, log)
        {
            m_ConfigurationRepository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(404)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromRoute] Guid orgId)
        {
            if (orgId == default)
                return BadRequest(nameof(orgId));
            return Ok();
        }
}
```

I tried to anonymize this, but the request I'm sending is basically the same exact thing in the screenshot. When I change the attribute to Post and do a Post request instead I can only get a 400 response.

Request with website name removed:
[Http Request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFoop.png)

Comment: You've provided nothing that can be used to diagnose the problem. No controller or action method code, no request details, no error details. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `[FromRoute] Guid orgId` - Where is "`{orgId}`" specified in the route. At the controller leve? Looks like you need to show more still.

Comment: Apologies, my first time asking a question here. I wanted to remove any identifiable information from the code. Fixed now.

Comment: And what does the request look like? Please read about how to provide a [mre].

Comment: Added a screenshot of the request in postman

Comment: `if (orgId == default)`  <-- do you know what `default` is in this context??

Comment: I'm 99% sure the orgId isn't the issue because the method isn't even being hit when I set a breakpoint. If I change the attribute to [HttpGet] instead using a valid orgId I get the 200 response as expected and the breakpoint is hit. I only put it as 0's in the screenshot to remove any potentially identifiable information.

Comment: Well, I was unable to reproduce the problem with the details you provided. I was also able to have two methods, identical in every way to each other and the one you posted with the exception of the name and the verb attribute, and I was able to call both from Postman. There's got to be something else getting in the way.

Comment: Well thank you for your patience and effort anyway, it was much appreciated.

Comment: See this link. Would this help? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45392

Answer (score -1):

[HttpPost("{orgId}")]

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.